# media webpart not working on ipad

Tags: web-part, media-streaming

We have  lot of videos that are hosted in our environment and we have used the OOTB media web part to show the video on page ,but the videos are not playing in Ipad .Is there any extra codec does we need to install for the web part to play the video on Ipad

Comment: try installing Silverlight plugin in Ipad see if it works ? if it does not then you need to create custom webpart using flash player.

Comment: Flash is not an option for iOS devices.  You would most likely have to create an HTML5 player

Comment: @ Dave but HTML 5 player will not work in IE 8 version and all our organization intranet computer are using IE8

Answer (score 1):

Posting the Solution which helped me ..These are steps for making videos in Document library to play in Ipad

1) In IIS add .mp4 to the mime type 
2)In web.config check for blob cache and set enabled =true and increase the maxsize

The above steps solved my problem

Complete Credit to the blog http://www.philadelphia-mtc.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=5c5feceb-5f6a-49da-8055-c10259e53bbb&ID=4&Web=48a882a4-7d38-485a-aec3-cf0f59839d6c  where i found my solution.